# `ElementType.FIELD` vs `ElementType.TYPE_USE`

Tags: java, annotations

I not fully understand the difference between annotating variable and annotating its type. 
Should I prefer type annotation over declaration annotation in this scenario?

```
@EmailField // can be used on String or Array/Collection of String-s
private String email;
private @EmailType String email2;
@EmailField
private List<@EmailType String> emails;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface EmailType {}

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@interface EmailField {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type annotations in Java 8 are mainly around to support stronger type checking.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html:

> Type annotations were created to support improved analysis of Java
>   programs way of ensuring stronger type checking. The Java SE 8 release
>   does not provide a type checking framework, but it allows you to write
>   (or download) a type checking framework that is implemented as one or
>   more pluggable modules that are used in conjunction with the Java
>   compiler.

From your above example, you should use the `@EmailField` field annotation, and you should also add `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` so that you can use reflection to check for this annotation at runtime as follows:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface EmailField {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference between declaration annotations and type annotations:

- A declaration annotation on a field gives information about the *variable*, such as that the field is deprecated and clients should use a getter method instead.
- A type annotation gives information about the *value*, such as that an integer value is greater than zero.

Your annotation gives information about the values:  the string should be a legal email address.  Therefore, you should use a type annotation, `@EmailType` (though I would just name it `@Email`).

You can validate a type annotation at compile time, run time, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example is still much easier to understand than many explanations.

TYPE_USE is use for this purpose :

private List<**@ValidEmail** String> emails;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).