# Java annotation ElementType.TYPE_USE

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java. I just confused when it comes to annotation `ElementType.TYPE_USE`. Code below comes from a book.

Is this statement a cast or what does it do.

```
int roundValue = (@NonZero int) value;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
  @interface Fatal {
}

@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
  @interface NonZero {
}

class TyepUseTest{
    public void processData() throws @Fatal Exception{
        double value = 10.89;
        int roundValue = (@NonZero int) value;
    }        
}
```

Comment: For the constraints you have to provide implementation and the validation logic, could you post the `ConstraintValidator` implementation code for `NonZero`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`ElementType.FIELD\` vs \`ElementType.TYPE\_USE\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898797/elementtype-field-vs-elementtype-type-use)

Comment: That's the complete example from a book.

Answer (score 2):

That statement is a type conversion (double to int).

Without the use of special annotation processor or reflection, most annotations can be ignored.
(All but the most basic like @Override)